# how to remove this link from facebook comment

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

How to remove the link at the bottom of the Facebook Comments Plugin which redirects to the Facebook Developer site?

http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/9095089?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1447851833&Signature=Q3xDPYfscSV5ANRh2ouoaDx%2FViI%3D

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove that link, and it´s not allowed to hide stuff from Social Plugins: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#socialplugins

> 13.4 Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins.